# reduce Screen brightness in battery mode automatically

Tags: indicator, screen, power-management, brightness, gnome-power-manager

KDE and XFCE4 has a program to adjust the screen brightness automatically in battery mode to a preset value.
How can i set the same with Unity ( or Gnome3 )?

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution:

If you have laptop-mode-tools installed

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
sudo -H gedit /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/lcd-brightness.conf
```

---

Contents should be:

```
DEBUG=0
CONTROL_BRIGHTNESS=1
BATT_BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND="echo [min value]"
LM_AC_BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND="echo [max value]"
NOLM_AC_BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND="echo [normal value]"
BRIGHTNESS_OUTPUT="/sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state"
```

---

**Sources**:

- [Arch Wiki: laptop-mode-tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop_Mode_Tools)
- [Gentoo forum](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-920202-start-0.html)

Comment: Shouldn't the last line (`BRIGHTNESS_OUTPUT`) point to `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` (or similar) rather than the cooling device?

Answer (score 7):

1. Download and install [Cuttlefish](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cuttlefish/)
   This tool helps in a lot of stimulus based reactions.
2. Install xbacklight
   `sudo apt-get install xbacklight`
   This tool helps in changing brightness via command line.
   Now make a file(say *dim*) with following content:
   `#!/bin/bash

   xbacklight -set 10`
   This command reduces your brightness *to* 10%.
   Change the mode of the file:`chmod +x dim`
3. Open the Cuttlefish application(using dash) and add a new reaction.Add a new stimulus *Power Cable Unplugged* from the Hardware category.

[image: Cuttlefish]

Next you need to set up the reaction.Go to *Reaction>Applications>Start Application(Advanced Mode)*

[image: Set Application]

Now choose the executable as *dim*(file that we created earlier)
[image: Set Application]

You may also want to increase the brightness when power is plugged again.For that follow the same steps except write `xbacklight -set 100` and change stimulus to *Power Cable Plugged In*.

To make it work, you need to enable cuttlefish to start automatically. Go to edit/preferences (within cuttlefish) and enable start up .

Comment: This is a great guide man, I also managed to change the governor for my 4 threads CPU with 
`cpufreq-selector --cpu 0 -g powersave` EDIT: You probably have more then one core so add that comand multiplied by threads: 4 threads = 4 comands and change them in order `--cpu 0` then next one `--cpu 1` and continue to reach number of cores or on Intel CPU's, threads ;)

Comment: EDIT: To change the GOVERNOR without `sudo` you need gnome applets. You can get them via terminal command: `sudo apt-get install gnome-applets`

Comment: Cuttlefish is only released for 12.04. For newer releases of Ubuntu, use the other answer.