# Automatically dim brightness if battery is low (command fail)

Tags: power-management, brightness, battery, 19.04, system-settings

I was trying to apply [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490250/automatically-dim-brightness-if-battery-is-low)  instructions on how to automatically dim brightness when battery is low, but in the answer, this command didn't work with me

```
> percent_left=$((100 * `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now` / ` cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full`))
```

It said

```
cat: /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now: No such file or directory
cat: /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full: No such file or directory
bash: 100 *  / : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ ")
```

Any solution!!
I'm a beginner Ubuntu user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install acpi:

```
$ sudo apt install acpi

$ acpi
```

View the battery percentage:

```
$ echo $(acpi | cut -f2 -d, | cut -c2- | cut -f1 -d%)%
```

Automatically dim brightness if battery is low:

```
$ A=$(acpi | cut -f2 -d, | cut -c2- | cut -f1 -d%)
$ B=15 # if low battery is <=15.
$ if [ "$A" -le "$B" ]; then xrandr --output VGA-1 --brightness .5; fi;
```

Here, 
VGA-1 is the screen.
Value of brightness is 50%. (--brightness .5)

I need your feedback ;)

Comment: the last command gives me this message : bash: [: 76-le: unary operator expected

Comment: @MohamedSaad `if [ "$A"-le "$B" ]` is missing a space, it should be `if [ "$A" -le "$B" ]`, typos happens...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my system:

```bash
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now
cat: /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now: No such file or directory
```

The reason is sometimes it is `BAT0` and sometimes it is `BAT1`. The solution is to search for either one like this:

```bash
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT*/charge_now
6216000
```

The `BAT*` wildcard lets it find either `BAT0` or `BAT1`.

The complete command then:

```bash
$ percent_left=$((100 * `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT*/charge_now` / ` cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT*/charge_full`))

$ echo $percent_left
100
```

Comment: it gives the same massage, either when I write BAT* or BAT0 or BAT1

Comment: @MohamedSaad It might be a **19.04** thing. I'm using **16.04**. I'll reboot into 19.04 later and check it out there.

Comment: @MohamedSaad I tied Ubuntu Unity 19.04 and it works ok. It might be a Ubuntu Gnome 19.04 problem so I'll reboot into that environment (where desktop icons disappear *sigh*) and test it.

Comment: @MohamedSaad Ubuntu Gnome 19.04 works ok. My last check will be Ubuntu Gnome Wayland (instead of xorg) 19.04.