# brightness not dimming on battery

Tags: power-management, brightness, battery

On my Lenovo Yoga Pad 2 with Ubuntu 14.04 there is no option to dim the screen when in battery mode.

There is one option "Dim screen to save power" but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

[image]

How can I set the brightness to another dim level on battery power in Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate answer provides two solutions: [reduce Screen brightness in battery mode automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183335/reduce-screen-brightness-in-battery-mode-automatically)

But for me in this case the solution was somewhat simpler: I just set the brightness to 50% on each system start in the startup programs (`gnome-session-properties`) with the command:

```
xbacklight -set 50%
```

---

**Info:** It doesn't work to call `xbacklight` in `rc.local`, see [set the screen brightness on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490725/set-the-screen-brightness-on-startup)

Because rc.local is not running in an X environment.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was marked as a duplicate. It is not.  The questions are completely different. Can someone please explain why it was marked as duplicate, because it does AskUbuntu serious reputational damage that this question would be marked a duplicate of the referenced question.