# set the screen brightness on startup

Tags: boot, screen, brightness

On Ubuntu 14.04 I tried to dim the screen brightness to 50% on each system start in `/etc/rc.local` with the line

```
xbacklight -set 50%
```

right before the line `exit 0`

Why does this not work?

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call xbacklight in `rc.local`, because rc.local is not running in the X environment.

Add this command to your startup programs (`gnome-session-properties`):

```
xbacklight -set 50%
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command to set my Surface Pro 3's brightness to 50%

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0.5
```

There are probably more direct ways to find your output names, but...

I installed and ran `arandr`.  After positioning my displays how I wanted them I saved a layout (they'll show up in `~/.screenlayout/yourLayout.sh`)

Then I modified that file to add the `--brigtness` flag, and configured the script to run at startup.